# DNN Search links not working after upgrade

Tags: search, dotnetnuke, upgrade

I have successfully upgraded DNN from version 4.9 to 7.4.1 using the following upgrade path:

```
4.9 --> 5.4 --> 5.6 --> 6.2 -->7.4.1
```

My problem is that whenever we search the test upgrade site, the search results are displayed normally (search part works)
only the links are not correct, they all point to:
http://mysite/SearchResults/tabid/37/Default.aspx?search=searchString 
[meaning I'm always redirected to the search page]

I have tried to do the following with no luck: 
1. Clear the Search folder under "AppData". 
2. Run the re-indexing.

Please can you help.

Comment: Have you made sure to merge any major web.config changes with the upgrades?  Also, you should have a friendlyUrl element in the web.config.  What is the defaultProvider currently set in the attribute?

Comment: @DotNetNuclear <br />
Yes all the web.config files were merged with each upgrade. <br />
Also there is a friendlyUrl element, as defined below:
    <friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" />
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>

Comment: I think you are missing the urlFormat="advanced" attribute.  Try <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="advanced" />